# Getting Error in Moodle 2.7 after installation

Tags: php, xampp, moodle

I Installed Moodle 2.7 by using XAMPP and it displayed the admin profile page. I am getting error if I proceed to any other page or open the application again

> Notice: Undefined variable: CFG in C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\index.php on line 31
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\index.php on line 31

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the `config.php` file isn't correct.

Have you got something like this at the top of your `/config.php` file

```
unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();
```

Have a look at `/config-dist.php` for an example.

Comment: I can find it in `config.php`